# refactor "render format" in multiple controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, controller

so i've got a view method in multiple controllers which mostly looks exactly the same:

```
  def show
    show! do |format|
      format.json do
        if @text.activated?
          @text.log
          render_for_api :texts_all, :json => @text
        else
          render :nothing => true
        end
      end
      format.pdf do
        pdf = QrPdf.new(@text)
        send_data pdf.render, filename: "text_#{@text.id}.pdf", type: "application/pdf"
      end
    end
  end
```

the models for this are different, but they all have the same attributes that are used in this method (`activated`, `log`, `id`). i also could change the `render_for_api` given hash from which is currently `texts_all`, `documents_all` etc to a hash that its everywhere the same.

is there a way to use this code in multiple models without having this enormous duplication?

i'm thankful for every hint!
especially i find it hard to deal with the `do |format|` block. but also i'm not sure where to put the code and how to use it with different types of models.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the model is truly generic:

```
def show
  show_model @text
end
```

I'm not sure what `show!` is, but that part you can figure out. Roughly (untested):

```
def show_model(obj)
  show! do |f|
    f.json do
      return render(:nothing => true) unless obj.activated?

      obj.log
      render_for_api :texts_all, :json => obj
    end

    f.pdf do
      opts = { filename: "text_#{obj.id}.pdf", type: "application/pdf" }
      send_data QrPdf.new(obj).render, opts
    end
  end
end
```

As far as where `show_model` lives, I tend to put things like that into a base controller, or as a mixin, but there may be better options. Since I usually have a base controller, it's just easy to keep it there.

Comment: That would have been my answer as well! Depending on the size/complexity of your app I'd just drop it in to ApplicationController as a private method

Comment: `show!` comes from the inherited_resources gem(https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources).

okay, so do you think i could put it inside my application_controller.rb. every controller inherits from this one, a good idea?

Comment: @choise There, or your own base controller--but it looks like `inherited_resources` has its own base class, so your app controller would need to extend that if it doesn't already. Also don't know what the base class method does (the `!` methods) so you'd need to make sure that was compatible with arbitrary models.